# Override Inline Styles with CSS for the google Ad div

Tags: css, overriding

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-131415161-0' style='height:250px; width:300px;'>
    <script>
       googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-131415161-0'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

I would like to override the above inline css with set to auto for both. I tried with the followings but not working ...

```
#div-gpt-ad-131415161-0 div[style] {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

OR

```
div[style]#div-gpt-ad-131415161-0 {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry the second one is working , might have cache issue before.

Answer (score 0):

When the style is defined in html, override any definition from external css. And uses only this definition.

So if you cand remove, style from html, will works. the las definition of css external about this div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the styles with javascript directly, this will change the inline css